# How the RSA algorithm (encryption and decryption) works in real life?

Tags: security, encryption, rsa

I understand how RSA algorithm goes with formulas, how we generate variables. I only want to know how can RSA be explained in real life. For example, if we have 2 people that want to communicate using RSA algorithm.

You can explain with Alice and Bob.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Comment: Is there a reason, you're asking this very basic question in light of the quite extensive Wikipedia article on RSA. What do you have trouble with understanding?

Comment: You need to consider Mallory and Eve too — it's easy to explain how Alice and Bob communicate, but if Mallory and Eve can understand the communication, it isn't very secret.

Comment: To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Public key cryptography allow communications without sharing a secret key.

Alice can create a key pair and make the public key available without it needing to keep it secret. Bob can encrypt a message with the public key and send that to Alice. Only Alice can decrypt the message. Note that Alice can not sent a message to Bob using the key pair.

One way this is used is for Bob to sent a symmetric key such as an AES key to Alice encrypted by Alice's public key and then they can send messages to each other with the symmetric key and symmetric key encryption such as AES.

One issue is how can Bob know he can trust Alice's public key, perhaps it was sent to him by Eve masquerading as Alice? PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) can be used to supply the public key as a part of a certificate signed by a trusted 3rd party, a CA (Certificate Authority) and a list of trusted CAs are included with most OSs.

Note that with public key cryptography there are costs. The recommended key sizes are generally 1024 to 2048 bits in size, the messages must be padded to the key size, the message size is limited to the key size and encryption/decryption is orders of magnitude slower than symmetric encryption. This mean that public key cryptography is generally only used when a public/private key pair is needed.

Asymmetric key encryption (ex: RSA) is no more secure than symmetric key encryption (ex: AES).

Answer (score 0):

`RSA` is a system for public-key encryption. It is mainly used to secure sensitive data, which can often be sent over insecure networks like the Internet.

Named after its three creators, Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir and Leonard Adleman, it was developed in 1977 at the Massachussetts Institute of Technology.

`Asymmetric Cryptography` uses two different, mathematically linked keys

- **Public Key** - Can be shared with anyone
- **Private Key** - Has to be kept secret

One of these keys is used to encrypt a message whereas another is used to decrypt it. This helps assure the confidentiality of electronic communications and data storage.

It has relationships to prime numbers. Its security is based on how hard it is to factor extremely large numbers that are the product of two separate large numbers.

In RSA, two prime numbers are generated with the help of the `Rabin-Miller Primality Test`. After multiplying these two numbers, a third number is derived which is the modulus of the two. This new number provides a link between the public and private keys.

The length of this number in bits is referred to as the `key number`. The public key is composed of the modulus, and an extremely large prime exponent (usually 65537). On the other hand, the private key is composed of the modulus and a secret exponent, which is calculated using the `Extended Euclidean Algorithm`.

Example

> Alice generates RSA keys by selecting two primes: *p=11* and *q=13*. The modulus n=p×q=143. The totient of n ϕ(n)=(p−1)x(q−1)=120. She chooses 7 for her RSA public key e and calculates her RSA private key using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm which results in 103.

Here's an interesting video that might be able to explain it a bit better

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXB-V_Keiu8

Reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)